# how to use a for loop to add extra attribute to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to Python, and thanks all for the help! Here is my current dictionary, I want to see how could I add an attribute (similar to weight, color,etc) called "Seen" with Value "False" to the dictionary with a for a loop.

```
rarebirds = {
    'Gold-crested Toucan': {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Color': 'Gold',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True
    },
    'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
        'Height (m)': 0.25,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'White',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False
    },
    'Four-metre Hummingbird': {
        'Height (m)': 0.6,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'Blue',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': False
    },
    'Giant Eagle': {
        'Height (m)': 1.5,
        'Weight (kg)': 52,
        'Color': 'Black and White',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True
    },
    'Ancient Vulture': {
        'Height (m)': 2.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 70,
        'Color': 'Brown',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False
    },
}
```

Comment: Add to each animal ?

Comment: What did you try so far to do it?

Comment: Always try to add some snippet or logic regarding what you have tried thus far to solve your problem, instead of asking for the answer directly. That helps the community be more specific in their responses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am new to python and trying to learn it during this special time at home. I appreciate the guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the dictionary values, to access them all, then just add the mapping

```
for attributes in rarebirds.values():
    attributes['seen'] = False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a dict for every key you can just use

```py
for k in rarebirds.keys():
    rarebirds[k]['Seen'] = False
```

Comment: It is enough to use `rarebirds` instead of `rarebirds.keys()` in this context.

Comment: Yes it is, iterating over dict is the same as iterating over keys